# Can't install python-ldap in Docker

Tags: docker, python-ldap

I'm getting the following error when trying to install python-ldap module in Docker image for aws:

```
      In file included from Modules/LDAPObject.c:3:0:
      Modules/common.h:15:10: fatal error: lber.h: No such file or directory
       #include <lber.h>
                ^~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-ldap
Failed to build python-ldap
ERROR: Could not build wheels for python-ldap, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
The command '/bin/sh -c pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt &&    pip install -r requirements.txt -t python' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

And my Dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

ARG TMP_BUILD=/tmp
ARG DIST=/opt/build-dist

RUN yum makecache fast; yum clean all && yum -y update && yum -y upgrade; yum clean all && \
    yum install -y yum-plugin-ovl; yum clean all && yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"; yum clean all

RUN yum -y install gcc gcc-c++ make autoconf aclocal automake libtool python-devel openldap-devel; yum clean all && \
 pip install --upgrade pip && pip install pipenv

WORKDIR ${TMP_BUILD}/build
COPY Pipfile .
COPY Pipfile.lock .

RUN pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt -t python
    # && \
    # find ./python -depth -path '*dist-info*' -delete && \
    # find ./python -depth -path '*test*' -delete && \
    # find ./python -depth -path '*pycache*' -delete

WORKDIR /opt
RUN mkdir -p ${DIST}/python && \
    cp -rf ${TMP_BUILD}/build/python ${DIST} && \
    cp -rf ${TMP_BUILD}/build/requirements.txt ${DIST}/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /var/task
```

This build used to work until recently and as you can see i have the python-devel openldap-devel packages so what's the problem?

Was also having trouble installing this module on my regular machine which runs ManjaroLinux. I had to build from source and change the name of a binary file manually. Could this be a similar situation?

Here is the Pipfile if it helps

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
requests = "*"
slack-bolt = "*"
slack-sdk = "*"
aiohttp = "*"
python-ldap = "*"

[dev-packages]
black = "*"
boto3 = "*"
pytest = "*"
pytest-runner = "*"
pytest-mock = "*"
pandas = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"

[scripts]
lint = "pipenv run black . --check"
"lint:fix" = "pipenv run black ."
integrationtest = "pipenv run pytest . -m integration "
test = "pipenv run pytest . -m 'not integration' --ignore-glob='integration.py' --junitxml=./TEST-results-lambdas.xml"

[pipenv]
allow_prereleases = true
```

Comment: You need to find and install the package which contains the missing header file `lber.h`. Probably something along the lines of `libldap-dev` though it could be a dependency of a dependency or etc. (Update: https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=lber.h&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any suggests `libldap2-dev`; but I see now that you are not on Debian, so you'll need to find whatever works for your distro.) When you have resolved that one, there will perhaps be others with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

**Below works - 2022**

`apt-get install build-essential python3-dev libmemcached-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libzbar-dev  ldap-utils tox lcov valgrind`

Sample:

```yaml
FROM python:3.10-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get --yes install build-essential python3-dev libmemcached-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libzbar-dev  ldap-utils tox lcov valgrind && \
apt-get clean
```

- I follow the official doc [python-ldap: Debian](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.3.0/installing.html) it stuck at `sldap` installation and prumpt input password.
- If remove `sldap` it said:
  `fatal error: libmemcached/memcached.h: No such file or directory`
- After replace `sldap` with `libmemcached-dev` problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Python relies on some packages to be present, in order to have them installed just add

```
RUN apt-get -y install libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev
```

on your Dockerfile

(or `yum install -y <package>` as per your example)